# jquery body delegate mouseover and mouseout fired at the same time

Tags: jquery, delegates

I have a delegate on body waiting for class thumbnail elements on mouseover and mouseout

```
 $('body').delegate('.thumbnail', 'mouseover mouseout', function(e){
            if(e.type=='mouseover' && !isMousingOver ){
              enlarge_thumbnail(this);
              isMousingOver = true;
              console.log('enlarged')
            }else if(e.type=='mouseout'){
              reset_thumbnail(this);
              isMousingOver = false;
              console.log('resetting')
            }
        })
```

but whenever I move the mouse over within the boundry of a div.thumbnail element, I get in the log
enlarged
resetting
enlarged
resetting
enlarged
resetting
enlarged
resetting
...

where enlarge_thumbnail and reset_thumbnail are:

```
function enlarge_thumbnail(element_to_set, how_much) {
    element_to_set = $(element_to_set); // jQueryize the element;
          how_much = parseInt(how_much);// Make sure it's an intger;
    if( element_to_set.length && !isNaN(how_much) ){
      element_to_set.css({width:how_much});
    }
  }

function reset_thumbnail(element_to_reset) {
    element_to_reset = $(element_to_reset); // jQueryize the element;
    element_to_reset.css({width:'200px'});
  }
```

If I don't move the mouse, and the mouse is stationary inside the boundry of a div.thumbnail element, then it does what I want: enlarging the thumbnail and NOT resetting it.

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because by design, `mouseover` and `mouseout` fire the handler when you enter/leave descendants of `.thumbnail` as well.

To avoid this, use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead. These events do not bubble, and as such will only fire when entering/leaving the `.thumbnail` element to which they're bound.